# How do I get a list that stores different styles I.E Button , Drag&Drop etc

Tags: c#, list, button, checkbox, drag-and-drop

```
public partial class QuestionDragAndDropList : Form
{
    private List<ListQuestions> Questions = new List<ListQuestions>();
    private int i = 0;


    public QuestionDragAndDropList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NextQuestion();
    }

    private void QuestionList()
    {
        Questions.Add(new ListQuestions("Question 1", new[] {//Answers}, 0));
        Questions.Add(new ListQuestions("Question 2", new[] {//^}, 0));
        Questions.Add(new ListQuestions("Question 3", new[] {//^}, 0));
        Questions.Add(new ListQuestions("Question 4", new[] {//^}, 0));
    }

    private void NextQuestion()
    {

        if (i != 2)
        {
            lblQuestion.Text = Questions[i].GetQuestion();
            string[] Ans = Questions[i].GetAns();
            BtnA1.Text = Ans[0];
            BtnA2.Text = Ans[1];
            BtnA3.Text = Ans[2];
            BtnA4.Text = Ans[3];
        }
        else
        {
            Questions[i].GetQuestion();
            BitMap[] Ans = Questions[i].GetAnswers();
        }
    }

    private void AnsCheck(int Answer)
    {
        if (Answer < Questions.Count)
        {
            WelcomeYear11.Userfiling.IncreaseS(); 
        }
        i++;
        if (i != Questions.Count)
        {
            NextQuestion();
        }
        else
        {
            do something.
        }
    }

    private void GrabLabel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Label selectedLbl = (Label)sender;
        selectedLbl.DoDragDrop(selectedLbl.Text, DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }
    private void AllowDragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }

    private void PBox1DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string result = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
        if (result == "9")
        {
            lblA1.Visible = false;
            PboxA1.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    private void PBox2DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string result = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
        if (result == "30")
        {
            LblA2.Visible = false;
            PBoxA2.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    private void PBox3DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string result = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
        if (result == "5")
        {
            LblA3.Visible = false;
            PBoxA3.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    private void PBox4DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string result = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
        if (result == "18")
        {
            LblA3.Visible = false;
            PBoxA3.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

So using this code, how am I able to not only have it set to generate forms with button questions but also with drag/drop, checkboxes, etc...
The ListClass used in the sample is:

```
class ListQuestions
{

    private string Questions; 
    private Bitmap[] Answers; private string[] Ans; //First is for Picbox questions. Second is for button questions.
    private int PosOfAns; 

    public ListQuestions(string questions, Bitmap[] answers, int posOfAns)
    {
        Questions = questions;
        Answers = answers;
        PosOfAns = posOfAns;
    }
    public ListQuestions(string questions, string[] ans, int posOfAns)
    {
        Questions = questions;
        Ans = ans;
        PosOfAns = posOfAns;
    }

    public string GetQuestion()
    {
        return Questions;
    }
    public string[] GetAns()
    {
        return Ans;
    }

    public Bitmap[] GetAnswers()
    {
        return Answers;
    }

    public int GetPosOfAns()
    {
        return PosOfAns;
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated :).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're after this

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

  Bitmap[] bm = { new Bitmap(1, 1) };//just had to make one to use in the ListQuestions method overload
  List<ListQuestions> thelist = new List<ListQuestions>();
  thelist.Add(new ListQuestions("", bm, 1));
```

Basically, you create your class, then you make a list of your class

```
List<ListQuestions> thelist = new List<ListQuestions>();
```

Then you can manipulate your list

```
thelist.Add(new ListQuestions("", bm, 1));
```

But since your class properties are all `private`, none of them are accessible outside of your class. So after you have added items to your List<>, you can't really access any of them. For example, this won't work until your properties are public.

```
string question = thelist[0].Questions;
```

Here's a working sample

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<myclass> mylist = new List<myclass>();
            mylist = Fillmylist(mylist);
            this.Controls.Add(mylist[0].chckbx_Recurse);
            this.Controls.Add(mylist[0].txtbx_pwd);
            this.Controls.Add(mylist[0].txtbx_usrname);
        }

        private List<myclass> Fillmylist(List<myclass> incominglist)
        {
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.Name = "txtbx_usr";
            tb.SetBounds(20, 20, 50, 10);
            TextBox tbp = new TextBox();
            tbp.Name = "txtbx_pwd";
            tbp.SetBounds(20,50, 50, 10);
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
            cb.Name = "chkbx_recurse";
            cb.SetBounds(20, 80, 20, 20);
            incominglist.Add(new myclass { txtbx_usrname = tb, txtbx_pwd = tbp, chckbx_Recurse = cb });
            return incominglist;
        }
    }



    class myclass
    {
        public TextBox txtbx_usrname { get; set; }
        public TextBox txtbx_pwd { get; set; }
        public CheckBox chckbx_Recurse { get; set; }

    }
}
```